# Performing update query then change page in Jquery Mobile

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I have a confirmation dialog that leads to an update query when the user clicks a link.

```
<div class="ui-bar">
    <a id="confirm" href="#" data-strid="<?php echo $str_info['str_id'] ?>">Confirm</a>
</div>
```

What I am looking to do is run an update query, then reload the previous page with the updated information on it.

I thought I accomplished this, but some sort of error keeps popping up in firebug and the ajax doesnt seem to be successful.  The error only comes when I reload the page...and when I put a delay on it, there is no error, so I can't even read what it is.

```
<script>
        $('#confirm').click(function (){
        var str_id = $("#confirm").data("strid");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: '../../ajax/add_land',
            dataType: 'json', 
            data: { str_id: str_id },
            success: function(){

            }
        });
        $('.ui-dialog').dialog('close')
        setTimeout(
            function() 
            {
                location.reload()
            }, 750);
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Is there any good way of accomplishing this? Again, in summary, I am looking to perform an update query, then reload the last viewed page (not the dialog) so that the changed info is displayed.  `../../ajax/add_land` is in PHP.

Comment: what sort of error? can you supply it in your question?

Comment: Also instead of `return false`, you might want to try `$('#confirm').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault();`

Comment: thanks i.  I took your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few better ways of achieving this but that is beyond the point, in your case you should do this:

```
<script>
        $('#confirm').click(function (){
        var str_id = $("#confirm").data("strid");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: '../../ajax/add_land',
            dataType: 'json', 
            data: { str_id: str_id },
            success: function(){
              $('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');            
              location.reload();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

When ajax call is successfully executed it will call code inside a **success** callback. Ajax call is asynchronous action, that means rest of the code is not going to wait for it to finish. Because of this success callback is used. So there's need for the timeout.

One more thing, there's also an error callback, use it to debug ajax problems:

```
error: function (request,error) {
    alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I originally had the dialog close and refresh inside the success callback, but it stops it from firing.  Im not exactly sure why ... and firebug doesn't seem to tell me much..I'll try and gather some errors

Comment: Well, it turns out I needed to include something in the success callback...so in php i added a `echo true` and in the ajax success added and `if (content == true) { do what i needed } ` and its working, however ugly :)

Comment: They probably stopped firing because of an error during an ajax call. So use an error callback to find an error.